# How can I manually specify a X-Cloud-Trace-Context header value to and correlate and trace logs in separate Cloud Run requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-tasks, google-cloud-trace

I'm using Cloud Run and Cloud Tasks to do some async processing of webhooks. When I get a request to my Cloud Run service, I queue up a task in my Cloud Tasks queue and return a response from my service immediately. Cloud Tasks will then trigger my service again (different endpoint) and do some processing. I want to correlate all the logs in these steps by using the same trace id, but it is not working.

When creating a task in Cloud Tasks, I request it to send the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header and I fill it with the original request's `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header value. Theoretically, when the request comes to my Cloud Run service from Cloud Tasks, it should have this header value, and all my logs will be correlated correctly. However, when this second request comes, it looks like Cloud Run is overriding the header with a new trace id.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? If not, what is the recommended solution to correlate all the logs (generated by service code and also the logs auto generated by GCP) in the steps described above?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

We found that passing along the traceparent header into the cloud task works. The trace id is preserved and a new span/parent id is automatically assigned by cloudrun.

```
 task = {
     "http_request": {
         "url": url,
         "headers": {
             "traceparent": request.headers.get('traceparent', "")
         }
     }
 }
```

Note it also appears to work with "X-Cloud-Trace-Context" but you have to split the value and only pass along the trace id (ex the cloudrun header value is like "trace_id/span_id;flags" -- you have to split out just the trace_id and set that as the task header value). Otherwise it seems like cloudrun considers the header invalid and, as you mentioned, sets a whole new trace context.

As a related note - while this gets the right header into place you still need to actually log the trace_id in some fashion for your logs to correlate.  Looks to me like the logs generated by cloudrun itself do this, but I had to configure my logger so that my logs would also be correlated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override the HTTP headers set by Cloud Tasks, but you can override the `trace` member in the log records sent to Stack Driver.

So you could include the original trace ID in the task payload and then override the `trace` in the logs produced by your Cloud Run endpoint which performs the real work.

Comment: You *can* set headers - https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#httprequest – just not `X-Google-` or `X-AppEngine-`. At least according to the docs!